# Build bitmap from view for map marker returns only background of the root element

Tags: android, google-maps, android-layout, bitmap

I am trying to build a custom bitmap by inflating a view, insert the values and get the drawingcache.

I managed to inflate it and get a picture of the mainview's background, but any view on top is not shown.
What am I missing?

```
LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(ctx);
View markerView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.marker_layout, null, false);
markerView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);

ImageView eventImage = (ImageView) markerView.findViewById(R.id.eventImage);
TextView textAttending = (TextView) markerView.findViewById(R.id.textAttending);
TextView textFriendsAttending = (TextView) markerView.findViewById(R.id.textFriendsAttending);


eventImage.setImageBitmap(noctisEvent.getPictureSmall());
textAttending.setText(noctisEvent.getAttending() + "");
textFriendsAttending.setText("nA");

markerView.layout(0, 0, 144, 144);

markerView.invalidate();
markerView.requestLayout();
markerView.buildDrawingCache();

markerBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(markerView.getDrawingCache());
```

The xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="144dp"
          android:layout_height="144dp"
    android:background="@drawable/marker_mask">

<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/eventImage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="68dp"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:background="#33ff0000"/>
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/textAttending"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="75dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:text="999"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="@color/g2"/>

<TextView
        android:id="@+id/textFriendsAttending"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="75dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="67dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:text="999"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="#330000ff" />

 </RelativeLayout>
```